# Magento 2 change max image height and width of image uploader in Admin?

Tags: magento2, adminhtml, image-upload

I want to change the `MAX_IMAGE_WIDTH` and `MAX_IMAGE_HEIGHT` constants of image uploader in Admin.

I think we should override **vendor/magento/framework/File/Uploader.php**. Can anyone give me a suggestion?

Comment: You want to change in Admin right? If you want to change these values in Admin, I'm pretty sure my answer can work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We **should not override the constant variables of class**.

If having already a custom admin theme, **you can override these templates in your custom admin theme**.

I saw some templates which use these constant variables:

`vendor/magento/module-backend/view/adminhtml/templates/media/uploader.phtml`

`vendor/magento/module-cms/view/adminhtml/templates/browser/content/uploader.phtml`

[image]

Read more here: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/frontend-dev-guide/themes/admin_theme_create.html

Answer (score 2):

I needed this only for product images and I didn't want to create a custom admin theme. So I used the event `catalog_product_gallery_prepare_layout`.

> adminhtml/events.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
<event name="catalog_product_gallery_prepare_layout">
    <observer name="vendor_module_catalog_product_gallery_prepare_layout" instance="Vendor\Module\Observer\CatalogProductGalleryPrepareLayout" />
</event>
```

> Observer/CatalogProductGalleryPrepareLayout.php

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class CatalogProductGalleryPrepareLayout implements ObserverInterface
{

    public function execute(Observer $observer)
    {
         $block = $observer->getBlock();
         if (!$block) return;

         $uploaderBlock = $block->getChildBlock('uploader');
         if (!$uploaderBlock) return;

         $uploaderBlock->setTemplate('Vendor_Module::media/uploader.phtml');
     }
 }
```

and of course you should override the template:

> view/adminhtml/templates/media/uploader.phtml

Comment: Thanks @marcus. It's working fine in magento 2.2.6 version

Answer (score 2):

As from **Magento 2.3.3** you no-longer need to change this setting by overriding files as it is configurable within the admin area:

`Stores > Configuration > Advanced > System > Images Upload Configuration`

[image]

Commit: https://github.com/magento/magento2/commit/88e26f2b958d6835f877d0feea8759418326a7f5

Answer (score 1):

You have to just create one module inside **app/code** folder.

Inside etc/di.xml file,

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Framework\File\Uploader" type="Vendor\Module\File\Uploader" />
</config>
```

*Now just create one folder under Module, File and create Uploader.php file.*

**app/code/Vendor/Module/File
Uploader.php file,**

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\File;

use Magento\Framework\Filesystem\DriverInterface;


class Uploader extends \Magento\Framework\File\Uploader
{
    /**
     * Uploaded file handle (copy of $_FILES[] element)
     *
     * @var array
     * @access protected
     */
    protected $_file;

    /**
     * Uploaded file mime type
     *
     * @var string
     * @access protected
     */
    protected $_fileMimeType;

    /**
     * Upload type. Used to right handle $_FILES array.
     *
     * @var \Magento\Framework\File\Uploader::SINGLE_STYLE|\Magento\Framework\File\Uploader::MULTIPLE_STYLE
     * @access protected
     */
    protected $_uploadType;

    /**
     * The name of uploaded file. By default it is original file name, but when
     * we will change file name, this variable will be changed too.
     *
     * @var string
     * @access protected
     */
    protected $_uploadedFileName;

    /**
     * The name of destination directory
     *
     * @var string
     * @access protected
     */
    protected $_uploadedFileDir;

    /**
     * If this variable is set to TRUE, our library will be able to automatically create
     * non-existent directories.
     *
     * @var bool
     * @access protected
     */
    protected $_allowCreateFolders = true;

    /**
     * If this variable is set to TRUE, uploaded file name will be changed if some file with the same
     * name already exists in the destination directory (if enabled).
     *
     * @var bool
     * @access protected
     */
    protected $_allowRenameFiles = false;

    /**
     * If this variable is set to TRUE, files dispertion will be supported.
     *
     * @var bool
     * @access protected
     */
    protected $_enableFilesDispersion = false;

    /**
     * This variable is used both with $_enableFilesDispersion == true
     * It helps to avoid problems after migrating from case-insensitive file system to case-insensitive
     * (e.g. NTFS->ext or ext->NTFS)
     *
     * @var bool
     * @access protected
     */
    protected $_caseInsensitiveFilenames = true;

    /**
     * @var string
     * @access protected
     */
    protected $_dispretionPath = null;

    /**
     * @var bool
     */
    protected $_fileExists = false;

    /**
     * @var null|string[]
     */
    protected $_allowedExtensions = null;

    /**
     * Validate callbacks storage
     *
     * @var array
     * @access protected
     */
    protected $_validateCallbacks = [];

    /**#@+
     * File upload type (multiple or single)
     */
    const SINGLE_STYLE = 0;

    const MULTIPLE_STYLE = 1;

    /**#@-*/

    /**
     * Temp file name empty code
     */
    const TMP_NAME_EMPTY = 666;

    /**
     * Max Image Width resolution in pixels. For image resizing on client side
     */
    const MAX_IMAGE_WIDTH = 1920;

    /**
     * Max Image Height resolution in pixels. For image resizing on client side
     */
    const MAX_IMAGE_HEIGHT = 1200;


}
```

Comment: i tried it, but it is not working