# Magento 2 - Why is product image size & dimensions changed after upload?

Tags: magento2, product-images, image-resizing

When uploading new images to a product in Magento 2, it is not only decreasing the dimensions of the image, but it's increasing the image file size:

**Image Details Before Upload**

- Dimensions: 1185 × 1580 px
- File Size: 446 KB

**After Upload**

[image]

Can anybody explain why this is happening? I accept that some data may be added to the image by Magento, but I don't understand why it has been resized? Is there anywhere this can be changed?

**EDIT**

I've now discovered that the image dimensions have been set in `vendor/magento/framework/File/Uploader.php`

[image]

Next is to find the best way to change these values, I found this related post: [Magento 2 change max image height and width of image uploader in Admin?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/153955/magento-2-change-max-image-height-and-width-of-image-uploader-in-admin)

I still don't know why these dimensions have been imposed on users on M2. nor why the file size more than doubles in size!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Default uploading image size in Magento 2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/144013/default-uploading-image-size-in-magento-2)

Answer (score 0):

In the end I created a new theme to override the following two files where the restriction was added:

- `vendor/magento/module-cms/view/adminhtml/templates/browser/content/uploader.phtml`
- `vendor/magento/module-backend/view/adminhtml/templates/media/uploader.phtml`

Within those files I hard coded the new max image sizes:

```
"maxWidth":3000,
"maxHeight":3000
```

This is the post I followed to achieve the override: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/153968/191

Regarding the image file size I have not found a definitive answer as to why the size has more than doubled. This post had some insight however: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14008524/why-smaller-png-image-takes-up-more-space-than-the-original-after-getting-resize

Answer (score 0):

Now the max image size can be set at
Stores > Settings > Configuration > Advanced > System > Images Upload Configuration

see
https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/catalog/product-image-resizing.html